# Setting lim in scale_y_reverse when plotting a ggdend object

Tags: r, ggplot2, dendextend

I have `dendrogram` which I `cut` the branches of for a given depth cutoff. I then want to plot it using `ggplot` and limit the flipped y-axis:

```
set.seed(10)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(24*10,mean=1,sd=2),nrow=24,ncol=10)
dend <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(mat)))
```

I save the depth of the dendrogram for limiting the plot:

```
require(data.tree)
dend.depth <- as.Node(dend)$plotHeight
```

I cut the `dendrogram`

```
depth.cutoff <- 11
dend <- cut(dend,h=depth.cutoff)$upper
```

I plot the cut `dendrogram` using `dendextend`

```
require(dendextend)
gg.dend <- as.ggdend(dend)
```

Plotting `gg.dend` without limiting the y-axis produces branches that do not end at the same line:

```
require(ggplot2)

ggplot(gg.dend,labels=F)+scale_y_reverse()+coord_flip()
```

[image]

So I thought I can fix that by limiting the y-axis to be between `dend.depth` and `depth.cutoff`. But this doesn't come out well:

```
ggplot(gg.dend,labels=F)+scale_y_reverse(lim=c(dend.depth,tol.level))+coord_flip()
```

[image]
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Use "hang parameter" and give it a negative value to level off all the branches

```
set.seed(10)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(24*10,mean=1,sd=2),nrow=24,ncol=10)
dend <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(scale(mat), method = "euclidean"), method="ward.D2"))
depth.cutoff <- 11
dend2 <- cut(dend, h=depth.cutoff)$upper
nodePar <- list(lab.cex = 0.6, pch = c(NA, 19), cex = 0.7, col = "blue")
plot(hang.dendrogram(dend2, hang = - 0.1),horiz = T, nodePar = nodePar )
```

Comment: I'd like to have it in ggplot though.

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating the gg.dend$seqments data.frame does it:

```
set.seed(10)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(24*10,mean=1,sd=2),nrow=24,ncol=10)
dend <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(mat)))
require(data.tree)
dend.depth <- as.Node(dend)$plotHeight
depth.cutoff <- 11
dend <- cut(dend,h=depth.cutoff)$upper
require(dendextend)
gg.dend <- as.ggdend(dend)
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(gg.dend,labels=F)+scale_y_reverse()+coord_flip()
```

[image]

Change vertical segments that lead to leaves to end at the highest leaf

```
leaf.heights <- dplyr::filter(gg.dend$nodes,!is.na(leaf))$height
leaf.seqments.idx <- which(gg.dend$segments$yend %in% leaf.heights)
gg.dend$segments$yend[leaf.seqments.idx] <- max(gg.dend$segments$yend[leaf.seqments.idx])
ggplot(gg.dend,labels=F)+scale_y_reverse()+coord_flip()
```

[image]